# Set visibility in Menu programmatically android

Tags: android

So, that´s what I wanna know. How can I set the visibility of the menu programatically in Android?? This is how I have my menu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menuregistrar:
            break;
        case R.id.menusalir:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But this code is not on the onCreate, so I don´t know how to set one item visible or invisible programmatically (in my case, I want the "menuregistrar" to be invisible once I have registered my application and forever.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Put this method in your `Activity`

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem register = menu.findItem(R.id.menuregistrar);      
    if(userRegistered) 
    {           
        register.setVisible(false);
    }
    else
    {
        register.setVisible(true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

in shorter version you could write:

```
MenuItem register = menu.findItem(R.id.menuregistrar);      
register.setVisible(!userRegistered);  //userRegistered is boolean, pointing if the user has registered or not.
return true;
```

Comment: Two tips: 1.you can tighten that up by writing `register.setVisible(userNotRegistered);` 2. Boolean variables are usually positive i.e. `if(!userRegistered)`. `if(!UsersNotRegistered)` is difficult to understand: if the user is NOt not-registered?

Comment: You might also want to do a `invalidateOptionsMenu();` to refresh the menu if the user already has it open.

Comment: Is there a way to set the menuitem GONE? Because it is taking space while not beeing seen...

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It can't find the menu item.

Answer (score 10):

I would simplify Adil's solution even further with the following:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem registrar = menu.findItem(R.id.menuregistrar);      
    registrar.setVisible(!isRegistered);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Its good, but some new users wouldn't get it, as they are in hurry and want to get there problem solved asap, so I expended it to show what is actually happening there. :)

Comment: @AdilSoomro, this code is simplier (and more convenient if "they are in hurry") than in your answer, so I'd suggest to edit the original answer.

Answer (score 6):

Simply do one thing get the id of the item of menu from this line:

```
Menu menu =navigationView.getMenu();

MenuItem nav_dashboard = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_dashboard);
```

and than make it visible it accourding to you by this line:

```
nav_dashboard.setVisible(true/false);
```

Answer (score 5):

Menu Object has a property to set the visibility of a menu's item using setVisible(boolean)//

Example

```
private Menu menu_change_language;
...

...

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ...
    ...
    menu_change_language = menu;
    ...
    ...

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

use code below for hiding Menu Item:

```
if(menu_change_language != null){                 
    menu_change_language.findItem(R.id.menu_change_language)
       .setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: this is useful if you want to visible menu after some certain operation. Thanks.

Comment: Kindly vote or promote this answer if you find it useful. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use `public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)` it is called everytime you press the menu button and do your stuff there. or use your oncreateoptionsmenu() in different activities to inflate different menus - this one is called only once.

Cheers

Comment: onPrepareOptionsMenu is also called any time you call invalidateOptionsMenu, so it may be called more than once.

Comment: @javahead76 this call will only work if `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the visibility inside the onOptionsItemSelected whenever you click the menu

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   item.setVisible(true);
   return true;
}
```

OR 
for item in the menu that you didn't click on

```
private Menu globalMenuItem;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu."menu Xml Name", menu);
   globalMenuItem = menu;
   return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   globalMenuItem.findItem(R.id."id of the menu item").setVisible(true);
   return true;
}
```