# How to change visibility for MenuItem dynamically?

Tags: android

I'm developing some Android application and I have ActionBar with 2 tabs. I need to show 2 icons on ActionBar when user select the second tab. I have the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    mOptionsMenu=menu;
    menu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
    menu.getItem(1).setVisible(false);
    return true;
} 

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        if (tab.getPosition()==1) {
        mOptionsMenu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
        mOptionsMenu.getItem(1).setVisible(true);
}
    }
```

But this code doesn't work. Please, tell me, how can I done my needs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the menu visible in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. You could change your code as follow:

```
private boolean menuShow = false;

public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) { 
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition()); 
    if (tab.getPosition()==1) { 
      menuShow = true;
    } 
}


public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  if(menuShow){
    mOptionsMenu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);    
    mOptionsMenu.getItem(1).setVisible(true);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to change visibility in an `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

See this answer: [Set visibility in Menu programatically android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030268/set-visibility-in-menu-programatically-android)