# Null pointer exception when onPageFinished() called in Android?

Tags: android, android-webview

When a webpage is called through webview, null pointer exception is being thrown on onPageFinished().  The problem persists only on Android 2.3, its working fine on Android 4.1. This is my code:

```
    public class StoreLocatorActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare WebView
    WebView storeLocator;
    final StoreLocatorActivity activity = this;

    boolean homeUrl = false;

    // Declare MenuItems
    MenuItem homeItem;
    MenuItem locationsItem;
    MenuItem preQualifyItem;
    MenuItem productsItem;
    MenuItem logOutItem;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
                Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_store_locator);

        setTitle("");


        // Changes to ActionBar
        /*ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY));
        bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);// This prevent icon from being
                                                    // displayed on ActionBar
*/    
        callHome();
        //logOutItem.setVisible(false).setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void callHome() {

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        storeLocator = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.storeLocator);
        storeLocator.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        //storeLocator.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // storeLocator.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        storeLocator.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressDialog.show();
                progressDialog.setProgress(0);
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);

                progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);

                if (progress == 100 && progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        storeLocator.loadUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.home));
        //storeLocator.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.24/EMG/Login.aspx");

        storeLocator.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                if (url.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.accounts))||url.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.accountsalt))) {
                    homeUrl = true;
                    System.out.println("in here!!!!!!");
                    logOutItem.setVisible(true).setEnabled(true);
                    preQualifyItem.setVisible(false).setEnabled(false);

                } else
                    logOutItem.setVisible(false).setEnabled(false);
                System.out.println("Changed url is " + url);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }
        });

    }
```

Menu ITems instantiation:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_store_locator, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    homeItem = menu.findItem(R.id.home);
    locationsItem = menu.findItem(R.id.location);
    preQualifyItem = menu.findItem(R.id.preQualify);
    productsItem = menu.findItem(R.id.products);
    logOutItem = menu.findItem(R.id.logOut);
    // logOutItem = menu.findItem(R.id.logOut);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.home:

        locationsItem.setIcon(R.drawable.locations72);
        preQualifyItem.setIcon(R.drawable.prequalify72);
        productsItem.setIcon(R.drawable.products72);
        // logOutItem.setVisible(true);

        item.setIcon(R.drawable.homeb);

        final ProgressDialog homeDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        homeDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        homeDialog.setCancelable(false);

        storeLocator = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.storeLocator);
        storeLocator.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        //storeLocator.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // storeLocator.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        storeLocator.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                homeDialog.show();
                homeDialog.setProgress(0);
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);

                homeDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);

                if (progress == 100 && homeDialog.isShowing())
                    homeDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
...........................................
```

This is exception:

```
05-02 14:06:42.632: E/AndroidRuntime(320): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-02 14:06:42.672: E/AndroidRuntime(320): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 14:06:42.672: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.emg.emgstorelocator.StoreLocatorActivity$2.onPageFinished(StoreLocatorActivity.java:117)
05-02 14:06:42.672: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:242)
05-02 14:06:42.672: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 14:06:42.672: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 14:06:42.672: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-02 14:06:42.672: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 14:06:42.672: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-02 14:06:42.672: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-02 14:06:42.672: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-02 14:06:42.672: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Unable to figure out reason for exception.

Comment: What's wrote on line 117 of StoreLocatorActivity ?

Comment: please indicate the 117th line of your StoreLocatorActivity

Comment: Are you sure that your MenuItems are initiated?

Comment: where u are initializing logOutItem and preQualifyItem MenuItem's?

Comment: Menu items code has been added in the edit

Comment: `logOutItem.setVisible(false).setEnabled(false);` this statement is at line# 117

Comment: you have to get id of this two view before set visibility: logOutItem &                   preQualifyItem like myview = (view)findviewbyid(R.id.myview);

Comment: @DhawalSodha can you please be more specific!!

Comment: mean you are set visibility to view. am i right? if yes then before sert visibility you have to find id(like: myview = (view)findviewbyid(R.id.myview)) have you dont this....??

Comment: @DhawalSodha If you are asking to add this step `MenuItem homeItem = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.home);` , it didn't work, it  threw `03-31 10:39:01.703: E/AndroidRuntime(2463): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView cannot be cast to android.view.Menu`

Comment: you are trying to set visibility in manuitem thats why it give you error remove this two line from your code: logOutItem.setVisible(true).setEnabled(true);
                    preQualifyItem.setVisible(false).setEnabled(false);

Comment: @DhawalSodha Thats the logic to be implemented... how can i remove those lines!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9030299/1168654

Comment: @DhawalSodha Thanks!! I'll implement and let you know!!