# Change an option menu to another

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to change the option menu to another, while running?
(I want that's when it logged, will be logout option, and will not be login and create account.)

Comment: You can make visible or invisible menu items

Comment: Can you give me an example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have common menu then you can change visibility of menu item like below.

You can override `onPrepareOptionsMenu` in your activity class.

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem register = menu.findItem(R.id.menuregistrar);      
    if(userRegistered) 
    {           
        register.setVisible(false);
    }
    else
    {
        register.setVisible(true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

in shorter version you could write:

```
MenuItem register = menu.findItem(R.id.menuregistrar);      
register.setVisible(!userRegistered);  //userRegistered is boolean, pointing if the user has registered or not.
return true;
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030299/6891563)

Comment: You can mark this answer right. If this is helped you.

Comment: And if I will do that's on logout, it will work, or the method called only one time?

Comment: You can create  `MenuItem` on class level and can call `menuItem.setVisible` many times