# What kind of Android component is used for Gmail selected item menu

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview, contextmenu, selecteditem

I am having trouble remembering what kind of Android component is being used to make the selected list item menu in their Gmail app. That is, when I open the app and see the list of emails in the inbox, I can long-press one of the items, and some sort of list shows up in the top of the screen, sort of like a context menu, with actions I can perform on the selected item(s). I would like to replicate similar functionality in one of my own apps. If I recall correctly there is a way of doing this using some standard Android UI component, but I'm having trouble finding what that is. Any pointers?

Comment: If you break your question in parts and do google search you will easily be going to get the answer

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030299/4079010

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551984/4079010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a [contextual actions bar](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/#contextual-action-bar). Details on how to create one are stored under the [menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#context-menu) section of the documentation as they relate to action items.