# How to show SearchView from Toolbar only in one Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app i have one activity with two fragment, the app has a toolbar with search action, that search action must be visible only in the second fragment.

So how could i hide the search button and show it only when i'm in fragment2?

My menu.xml looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="it.gabtamagnini.visualstock.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/cerca"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

I'm using kotlin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set visibility in Menu programmatically android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030268/set-visibility-in-menu-programmatically-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding the following code in my `onViewCreated`

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

And i had to override the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` like this:

```
override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    val item: MenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search)
    item.isVisible = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second fragment:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search);

if(item != null)
{
         
  item.setVisible(false);

}

}
```